# How can I combine lines and brush at the same time?

Tags: lines, area, brush

I have been using this d3 example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 But my question is if I add lines in the extremes of the brush where each point match the points on the focus area?  I think it looks like a "torch"  I add a picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgZUr.jpg

Regards.